# SQL Query to retrieve rows having conditional values in a column

Tags: sql

I don't know if this question has been asked previously also. If so please direct me to the link.

I have a table that has three columns `name`, `type` and `date`. `Type` can only be 4 values A, B, C and D

I want to fetch all those records which are of type A, B or C but the condition is that it should only fetch if the same name also has a type of D.

e.g. lets consider this table

```
Name      type    Date 
abc        A       5/7
abc        B       6/7
abc        D       7/7

xyz        A       5/7
xyz        D       6/7

lmn        A       5/7
lmn        B       6/7
lmn        C       7/7
```

So the deal here I need the following result set

```
ABC 5/7
ABC 6/7
XYZ 5/7
```

Because ABC and XYZ has a `type` D the other records of ABC and XYZ are shown. Since lmn does not have a `type` D it's not included in the result set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test if a record exist, you can simply use `where exists` :

```
select * from mytable t1 where exists (
     select * from mytable t2 where t1.Name=t2.Name and t2.type="D"
);
```

That's probably self explanatory but here's a reference : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

If you want to exclude the D records, you do this :

```
select * from mytable t1 where t1.type<>"D" and exists (
     select * from mytable t2 where t1.Name=t2.Name and t2.type="D"
);
```

Comment: I believe this would return 3 records for `ABC` and 2 records for `XYZ`.

Comment: I reread the requirement and you're right. I edited my answer by adding a second query, that's a minor adjustment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Name, Date
FROM MyTable as mt
WHERE type != 'D'
AND EXISTS
(
   SELECT * FROM MyTable as mt2
   WHERE mt2.type = 'D' and mt2.name = mt.name
)
```

You are selecting all records where type is not equal to `D` and that have a record with a matching name where type IS equal to `D`

Answer (score 0):

```
create view all_D as select name from your_table where type=D
select * from your_table where type<>D and name in (select * from all_D)
```

You could even make it such that instead of having that view you jut put that query in the brackets after "not in"